# Execute autocommand in vim

Tags: vim

I am using SimpleFold for folding vim. I mapped it to a key setting:

`map <unique> <silent> <Leader>f <Plug>SimpleFold_Foldsearch`

However, I would like to set it up as an auto command.  I tried adding this line to my `.vimrc` file:

`autocmd FileType ruby <Plug>SimpleFold_Foldsearch`

But, I just get an error now when I open a ruby file. Can anybody help me setup the autocmd so that it works?

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:autocmd` is executing Ex mode commands, so your code is wrong. You should be using `:normal` or `feedkeys()`:

```
autocmd FileType ruby :execute "normal \<Plug>SimpleFold_Foldsearch"
```